# Why doesnt the page preserve the data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

So I'm currently looking at the Blazor example project.. The "Counter" to be more specific, and when I increment the value on the page, and then click a different tab on the webapp, let's say the "Fetch data" tab which pulls up the weather, and then I go back, the value that was incremented is back to 0.. Why is that? Why isn't it saved?

Here is the NavMenu

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the Counter

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

[image: asp.net]

Comment: Seems legit to me. It’s defined as a local variable, so assuming any sort of new instance creation on a page load occurs, the reset behavior is “expected”. Are some examples on how to save / preserve data?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ba16f6bb6934842d78c89ab5314f4b56 which explains how store and resume state.

Comment: I just figured that it would preserve the data.. Let's say i was changing the background of a button, and I wanted it to be saved while I was browsing different tabs. Wouldn't it be changed back to default at that point? Just like the int?

Comment: I thought that was part of the idea of a SPA as well

Comment: SPA doesn’t mean that views are singletons. If a new instance is created, a new instance is created. Any old instance state is discarded (maybe views can be created as singletons *shrug*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. When your Counter Page Component goes out of scope it is destroyed, and when you go back, it is re-created. But you can cache its state (the count value) and read the last value when you go back to the page. You may save the state value in the local storage or session storage (JavaScript Api), which you can use directly employing the JSInterop feature of Blazor, or still better, use libraries design to work with Blazor created by the Blazor community, and even by the Blazor team (recommended)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Components are created/destroyed as needed, even within a single page if they are displayed / hidden. Therefore, any state they hold is lost along with the component that has disappeared.

Components are designed for rendering visuals and managing interaction. They can hold some state, but not state across their own lifetimes. To achieve this you need to store the state elsewhere, in a service for example.

I wrote Fluxor to deal with this scenario: https://github.com/mrpmorris/fluxor

Someone created a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_c-ErPaYa8

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is, State Management.
When you change your state for each user and you want to keep the state, then you need to save the state.

There are several methods (like caching) to perform this,
Take a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1)